# The list of harms in Daniel Sjoberg's SAS macro DCA.sas

Tags: sas, macros

I want to run Daniel Sjoberg's SAS macro DCA.sas, available at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ddsjoberg/dca.sas/main/dca.sas

My outcome variable is Cancer (1/0), the three variables with the predicted probabilities are called pred1, pred2, pred3. How should I list the harms to apply to each predictor?

I provided harms as harm=3 3 3. The error message :   The specified number of harms and indicators of probability must be equal to the number of predictors specified.

Comment: You need to show your code and log.  From a glance at the macro definition if you have these parameter values: `,harm=3 3 3,predictors=pred1 pred2 pred3`  then the number o harms will match the number of predictors.